# XAML: Binding scrollviewer with 2 sources

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone

Trying to learn xaml designing. I got this picture from internet and use it as a model to practice. There is a problem: When I click one of day buttons, a scrollviewer with a list of day tasks appears. Each task has a list of hours in day, from start time to end time. I don't know whether they are from one source or 2 source (one describes day task and the other one is a list of hours of this task).
 [image]

I tried with this

```
public async void ShowTasks()
    {
        ObservableCollection<DayTask> Data = await App.DataSource.GetData();
        DateListBox.ItemsSource = Data;

        DayTask daytask = Data.Where(x => x.Day.Date == App.Day.Date).FirstOrDefault();
        TasksListView.ItemsSource = daytask.Tasks;

        List<HoursModel> HoursList = new List<HoursModel>();
        foreach (var simpletask in daytask.Tasks)
        {
            HoursList.Add(new HoursModel(simpletask.StartTimeHour, simpletask.EndTimeHour));
        }
        HoursListView.ItemSource = HoursList;
    }
```

This is my xaml code:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="730" Width="300" >
            <ListView 
                    x:Name="TasksListView" Height="730" Width="300" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>                                                      
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ListView 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                x:Name="HoursListView">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock 
                                            x:Name="ShowedHours"
                                            Text="{Binding}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <Rectangle 
                                    Fill="Pink"
                                    Height="75"
                                    Width="150"
                                    Margin="60,20,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock
                                    Text="{Binding Description}"
                                    FontSize="17"
                                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                    Margin="80,20,0,0"/>
                            </Grid>


                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

I got an error with `HoursListView.ItemSource = HoursList;`. The detail of this error is
`The name 'HoursListView' does not exist in the current context`.  Does anyone have any suggestions how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access control in `DataTemplate` directly by it's name. That makes sense because `DataTemplate` in this case is generated repeatedly for each item within `TasksListView`.

According to XAML markup posted, you want to have different `HoursList` for each `DayTask`. That can be achieved by adding an `HoursList` property in `DayTask` class. I'd suggest to use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` because the former has built-in feature to notify bound UI to refresh whenever item added to or removed from collection :

```
public class DayTask
{
    public ObservableCollection<HoursModel> HoursList { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

Then bind `HoursListView`'s `ItemsSource` to above property :

```
.....
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>                                                      
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView 
            Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding HoursList}"
            x:Name="HoursListView">
            .....
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
.....
```

Don't forget to populate all `HoursList` properties before setting `DateListBox.ItemsSource`.